# How to work with languages without explicit tokens, e.g. Turkish?

Tags: python, nlp

I am new in NLP subject. 
I am working on Turkish so it is hard to find a proper corpus. I read a lot and found this https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/wiki.html#preparing-the-corpus it tells to use Wikipedia data but even if I use it will not give me the stems of words because of the structure of the language(agglutinative language).

My aim is to put my texts into some categories.

Result must be like 
text1 related to subject1 20% and subject2 50% and subject3 30%

I thought that what if I try to do it without a corpus but first wanted to ask here if my idea is possible or utopic.

Also, I will need categories and words related with them. 
If someone can show me a path to go on that will be great I am drifting inside this topic.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried a web search for "Turkish NLP"? Because when I did, I found a couple of pages with links to resources – including corpora and a morphological analyser. Have you seen Deniz Yuret's homepage?

Comment: @lenz is right, Deniz Yuret is the person to look to =)

Comment: Thx both of you guys I checked him he has a few corpuses which the words are with their suffixes. But still good. I think I will search more and then decide what to do.